# Open specific activity based on current value of URL in webView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, url, webview

I have a URL (`www.abc.com`) that I have opened in a webview of an activity inside my app. I want to develop a flow such that when user surfing the URL inside the webview reaches to particular URL inside the webview let's say `www.abc.com/foo` then app should handle it and open a specific activity. How can I capture the URL and open specific activities based on the current value of URL

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: So if I add deeplink intent filter to an activity, will it be observing my current URL value from a webview?

Comment: the webview class of android won't do it. For that you need to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method and write your logic. But browsers like chrome/firefox etc will automatically do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works for me**

Create a `webClient` and override the `onPageFinished` method to get current value of URL after loading of each page

```
    wv_content.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            Log.v("Current value of URL: ", URL)

            //handle URL like open an activity based on the value of URL
            handleCurrentUrl(url)

            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            pb_loading.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```